# Excel VBA Copy paste into cell doesnt trigger worksheet_change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format a date into a fixed format everytime someone changes cell B8, entering data manually seems to trigger Macro-checkdateformat but when copy pasting into cell doesnt trigger.

Below is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = "$B$8" Then

Call Checkdateformat

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It should trigger if the **only** cell being pasted to is `B8`, but if you were pasting to `B8:B10` then `Target.Address = "$B$8"` will be `False` (because the address is actually `"$B$8:$B$10"`).  If that is likely to be the reason, Jeeped's answer should fix things.

Comment: @yowE3K I am actually pasting only on one cell but thanks for your idea and Jeeped's answer works for me as well. cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target can be more than a single cell. You just need to check if B8 is one of them.  To see if a cell is in a larger group of cells (or just one other cell), use Intersect.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    If not intersect(target, range("B8")) is nothing then
        'B8 is part of Target
         on error goto safe_exit
         application.enableevents = false
         Call Checkdateformat
    End If

    safe_exit:
         application.enableevents = true

End Sub
```